# Find the default application name for a given file

Tags: python, linux

In Linux, is there a way to ask any xdg services, or gtk services, which application is the default application for a given file?

I realize that **xdg-open** will in fact, launch the correct application.  However, I want to be able to display the application's name in a context menu.  So that when the user clicks on the menu item, it will then launch xdg-open, which will launch that app.

On OSX I can use LaunchServices for this:

```
def getDefaultDarwinApplication(path):
    import LaunchServices
    import CoreData
    import urllib

    url = CoreData.CFURLRef.URLWithString_("file://"+urllib.quote(path))
    os_status, app_ref, appurl = LaunchServices.LSGetApplicationForURL(url, LaunchServices.kLSRolesAll, None, None)
    if os_status != 0:
        return ""
    apppath = app_ref.as_pathname()
    name = os.path.basename(apppath).replace(".app", "")
    return name
```

The hope is that there is something similar on Linux I can use.  A builtin python module would be best, but even screen scraping would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better I found [the official gnome way](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gioappinfo.html) to do this.

```
import gio
mime_type = gio.content_type_guess('foo.txt')
app_infos = gio.gio.app_info_get_all_for_type(mime_type)
for app_info in app_infos:
    print app_info.get_name(), app_info.get_executable(), app_info.get_icon()
# pure bliss
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `xdg-mime` command. It allows you to query for a mimetype, and then get the program associated, without executing it.

Note that this returns the name of the associated `.desktop` file. Then you have to locate the actual file and further parse it to get the real name of the program, even localized in any language you want, path of the binary in the disk, etc.

Here's the full code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import codecs
import ConfigParser

class XDGError(Exception): pass
class FileNotFoundError(Exception): pass

def _get_app_paths():
    paths = os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_HOME', 
        os.path.expanduser('~/.local/share/')).split(os.path.pathsep)
    paths.extend(os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_DIRS', 
        '/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/').split(os.path.pathsep))
    return paths

def xdg_query(command, parameter):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-mime', 'query', command, parameter], 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode or errors:
        raise XDGError('xdg-mime returned error code %d: %s' % 
            (p.returncode, errors.strip()))
    return output.strip()

def locate_desktop_file(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8', 
        _paths=_get_app_paths()):
    for path in _paths:
        for thispath, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, 'applications')):
            if filename not in files:
                continue
            fullname = os.path.join(thispath, filename)
            try:
                return codecs.open(fullname, mode, encoding)
            except IOError:
                pass
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError(filename)

def get_defaults(filename):
    filetype = xdg_query('filetype', filename)
    desktop_filename = xdg_query('default', filetype)
    with locate_desktop_file(desktop_filename) as desktop_file:
        parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        parser.readfp(desktop_file, desktop_filename)
    return dict(parser.items(parser.sections()[0]))
```

Example usage:

```
p = get_defaults('index.html')
print p['name'], p['comment']
```

Comment: This will not properly locate per user `.desktop` files (such as those created for custom associations) as those live in `$XDG_DATA_HOME` or `~/.local/share/` if the first is unset. You need to look in that directory before going to those named in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. This is stated in the xdg base dir spec. Althought not as clearly as i would like.

Comment: Additionally, you also have to scan all subdirectories of `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` to find desktop files with vendor prefixes (as stated by the XDG Menu specification, section Merging).

Comment: @Dan D.: Thank you for your comment, I have modified the code above to follow that spec.

Comment: @lunaryorn: Good catch, I'm now scanning subdirectories.

Comment: I also found some code in python-xdg to help with some of this.
    from xdg import BaseDirectory
    obj = BaseDirectory.load_data_paths("applications", desktop_filename)
This will get rid of the _get_app_paths() method for us.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more compact version using some methods from the official xdg python module and using some of the great code from @nosklo:

```
import os
import subprocess

from xdg import BaseDirectory
from xdg import DesktopEntry

class XDGError(Exception): pass

def xdg_query(command, parameter):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-mime', 'query', command, parameter],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode or errors:
        raise XDGError('xdg-mime returned error code %d: %s' %
            (p.returncode, errors.strip()))
    return output.strip()


def get_default(filename):
    try:
        filetype = xdg_query('filetype', filename)
        desktop_filename = xdg_query('default', filetype)
    except XDGError:
        return None

    try:
        res = BaseDirectory.load_data_paths('applications', desktop_filename)
        if not res:
           return None
        desktop_file = res.next()
    except StopIteration:
        return None

    if not os.path.exists(desktop_file):
        return None
    return DesktopEntry.DesktopEntry(desktop_file)
```

And an example of how to use it:

```
entry = get_default("index.html")
if not entry:
    print "no default application found"
else:
    application_name = entry.getName()
    application_path = entry.getExec()
    application_icon = entry.getIcon()
```